# java "error cannot open file" jar

Tags: java, compiler-construction

I can't run the class or jar file it gives me the "Error cannot open file".

I'm using the following commands:

```
javac src/*.java

jar cfe MyJar.jar src.Main src/*.class

java -jar MyJar.jar
```

Output:

```
javac src/*.java
jar cfe MyJar.jar src.Main src/*.class
java -jar MyJar.jar
Error cannot open file
C^%
```

I'm using linux/ubuntu and java:

```
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.5) (6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~12.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

Content of MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.6.0_24 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: src.Main
```

Comment: Obviously, you haven't defined main class in your manifest.

Comment: Obviously, I have defined the main class in my manifest using the `e` option of the `jar` command.

Comment: Have you tried `java -jar ./MyJar.jar` ?

Comment: Are you sure the error is not printed by your main program?

Comment: My experience on Java programming in GNU/Linux platform: the user and the permission of **java** command allow to manipulate the file and *vice versa*?

Comment: Actually yes. Without noticing it, it actually is an error of my program. I didn't think so because it was the only output I got at all even though it was supposed to output more. I'm gonna look into why.... I somehow feel kinda ashamed now...

Comment: Shame is just an alternative way of successfully processing critical, yet constructive feedback :)

Comment: @PascalNeubert Oops, sorry, didn't notice this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was actually output from the FileHandler class I made. I feel kinda ashamed now. I'm going to look into it why it didn't print more than the caught exception. Thank you for taking your time and make me notice.

Comment: Don't worry, but remember to receive always the stackTrace where you want (console, file, database, mail, etc)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced the error is actually on the `java -jar` command. I suspect it's the `jar` command having a problem finding `src.Main`. Try `jar cfe MyJar.jar src/*.class` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I am quite sure the error message should read:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile MyJar.jar
```

In any case, the actual file name would be printed.

hence, I guess it is simply the code in the jar files that prints the error.

An easy test:

```
jar -jar MyJar.jar "this is so stupid"
```

Is the output then

```
Error: cannot open file this is so stupid
```

If so, you consult your source code.